# Python data structure for a indexable list of string

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I got a list of objects which look like strings, but are not real strings (think about mmap'ed files). Like this:

```
x = [ "abc", "defgh", "ij" ]
```

What i want is `x` to be directly indexable like it was a big string, i.e.:

```
(x[4] == "e") is True
```

(Of course I don't want to do "".join(x) which would merge all strings, because reading a string is too expensive in my case. Remember it's mmap'ed files.).

This is easy if you iterate over the entire list, but it seems to be O(n). So I've implemented `__getitem__` more efficiently by creating such a list:

```
x = [ (0, "abc"), (3, "defgh"), (8, "ij") ]
```

Therefore I can do a binary search in `__getitem__` to quickly find the tuple with the right data and then indexing its string. This works quite well.

I see how to implement `__setitem__`, but it seems so boring, I'm wondering if there's not something that already does that.

To be more precise, this is how the data structure should honor `__setitem__`:

```
>>> x = [ "abc", "defgh", "ij" ]
>>> x[2:10] = "12345678"
>>> x
[ "ab", "12345678", "j" ]
```

I'd take any idea about such a data structure implementation, name or any hint.

Comment: "Of course I don't want to do "".join(x) which would merge all strings?"  Why not? "reading a string is too expensive in my case" What does that have to do with anything?  What -- exactly -- is wrong with the join?

Comment: Because the strings in the list are not really strings. They are (sort of) mmap'ed files. But they just work like strings (they implement `__getitem__`).

Comment: x[4] == e because `__getitem__` is overloaded in `x` class (a subclass of list).

Comment: @Woot4Moo: If you joined all the strings together into one, 'e' is at index 4.

Comment: A couple of notes: **1**) If I understand correctly how you're using that list of tuples, element [1][0] should be 3 rather than 4, and [2][0] should be 8.  **2**) `x[4] == "e" is True` will be false unless `x[4] == false`, since `is` has higher precedence (binds more tightly) than `==`.  You probably mean `(x[4] == "e") is True`.

Comment: @Kirk `x = [ (0, "abc"), (4, "defgh"), (9, "ij") ] ` is what threw me off.

Comment: @jd_: "the strings in the list are not really strings".  Then please fix the question to state what the **really** are.  Right now, the question is misleading.

Comment: @intuited and @S.Lott: I've fixed that in the question, thanks for the suggestion/fix. :)

Comment: In the `__setitem__` example at the end of your question, why does `x[2:10] = "12345678"` result in `[ "ab", "12345678", "j" ]` rather than `[ "ab1", "23456", "78" ]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are describing is a special case of the [rope data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29).

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any Python implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Indeed, it really looks like it. :)

Comment: PyPy implements the rope data structure does it not? - http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2007/11/ropes-branch-merged.html

Answer (score 0):

So do you still want to be able to address the n'th list element at all, like find that `x.somemethod(2) == 'ij'`?
If not, then your data structure is just a string with some methods to make it mutable and to initialize it from a list of strings.

If you do want to be able to, then your data structure is still a string with those extra methods, plus another element to track the ranges where its elements came from, like `x.camefrom(1) == (3, 7)`.

Either way, it appears that you want to be storing and manipulating a string.

Comment: You missed the part where I wrote "I don't want to read the string". If I understand you correctly, creating a string initialized from a list of string means reading all the strings and copying them. :)

Comment: I didn't miss it. I ignored it because it sounded like you're making things a lot harder than you need to, without explaining why you want to do it the hard way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a start:

```
self._h = {0:"abc", 3:"defgh", 8:"ij"} #create _h and __len__ in __init__
self.__len__ = 10

def __getitem__(i):
    if i >= self.__len__:
        raise IndexError
    o=0
    while True:
        if i-o in self._h:
            return self._h[i-o][o]
        o+=1
```

improvements contain mutability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that does what you want.

However, if you've implemented  `__getitem__` efficiently the way you say, then you already have the code that maps an index to your tuple, string list. Therefore it seems like you could just reuse that bit of code -- with a little refactoring -- to implement `__setitem__` which needs the same information to perform its function.

Answer (score -1):

You have recreated the dictionary data type.

Comment: Not exactly. In a dictionary, you cannot trivially find the character at position `i` if `i` is not the start of one of the substrings.

Comment: Not every key corresponds directly to one the strings in his list. If you mean it's conceptually a dictionary, that's not true either since there can be no `i` between `0` and `len(op_s_object)` s.t. `op_s_object[i]` has no value.

Comment: The op's explanation is lacking something, for instance he has yet to explain how x[4] == e.  Is he overriding equals to mean contains:?

Comment: "What i want is `x` to be directly indexable like it is a big string" -- I take this to mean he's building a sequence type, i.e. a string by different means.

Comment: why not just use a character array which already has O(1) lookup.  Or perhaps its O(n) I forget.

Comment: I believe the OP wants O(1) string concat. I'm not arguing the usefulness of this approach :)

Comment: isn't concat O(1) if it is at the end.  The reason why it isn't in the middle is the array needs to be resized.  Or am I seeing that the wrong way.

Comment: Concat is O(n) in Python since strings are immutable, so they have to copied. For lists, it's O(1) amortized.

Comment: Well there is no free lunch at the end of the day.  Therefore the entire process is still O(n)